# PayPal IPN issue using Codeigniter while retrieving IPN responses

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn, cart

I have utilized [this_for_reference](https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-add-to-cart-multiple-items-php/) (which worked fine).

**The issues which I face:** 
When I tried to implement the [same](https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-add-to-cart-multiple-items-php/) with CodeIgniter for cart payment using PayPal, I could get the transaction completed for the payments. The IPN messages were generated on the PayPal side [Instant Payment Notification (IPN) details]. But I could not retrieve IPN messages with the notify URL or to the success URL provided below, thus the database is not getting updated.

This is the View file, where I add items to cart then to PayPal payment.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php if(!empty($products)): foreach($products as $row): ?>
    <div class="thumbnail">

        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{My PayPal email ID}">

            <!-- Specify a PayPal Shopping Cart Add to Cart button. -->
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

            <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $row['item_number']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

            <!-- Specify URLs -->
            <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://{MyDomain}/paypal/cancel'>
            <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://{MyDomain}/paypal/success'>

//Notification URL is actually "http://{MyDomain}/paypal/ipn",
 but it's **not a typo error** in my actual code. 
I still face issues, mentioned in my Question.
{Preston PHX} It was a good catch//

            <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://{MyDomain}/paypal/ipn'>

            <!-- Display the payment button. -->
            <input type="image" name="submit"
              src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_addtocart_120x26.png"
              alt="Add to Cart">
            <img alt="" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
        </form>

    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

</div>
```

PayPal IPN function

```
public function ipn()
    {   
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval)  {
            $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2)
            {
                $my_post[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
        }

        // Read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        /*
         * Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
         * Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
         */
        $paypalURL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        $ch = curl_init($paypalURL);
        if ($ch == FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

        // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        /*
         * Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
         * Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
         */ 
        $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
        $res = trim(end($tokens));
        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

            //Payment data
            $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $payment_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            $currency_code = $_POST['mc_currency'];
            $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
            $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

            //Check if payment data exists with the same TXN ID.
            $prevPayment = $this->db->query("SELECT payment_id FROM payment WHERE txn_id = '".$txn_id."'");
            if($prevPayment->get()->num_rows() > 0){
                exit();
            }else{
                //Insert tansaction data into the database

                $insertPayment = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO payment(txn_id,payment_gross,currency_code,payment_status,payer_email) VALUES('".$txn_id."','".$payment_gross."','".$currency_code."','".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."')");
                if($insertPayment){
                    //Insert order items into the database
                    $payment_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                    $num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
                    for($i=1;$i<=$num_cart_items;$i++){
                        $order_item_number = $_POST['item_number'.$i];
                        $order_item_quantity = $_POST['quantity'.$i];
                        $order_item_gross_amount = $_POST['mc_gross_'.$i];
                        $insertOrderItem = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO order_items(payment_id,item_number,quantity,gross_amount) VALUES('".$payment_id."','".$order_item_number."','".$order_item_quantity."','".$order_item_gross_amount."')");
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        }
```

PayPal Success function

```
public function success(){
            $txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
            $payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
            $currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
            $payment_status = $_GET['st'];

            if(!empty($txn_id)){
                //Check if payment data exists with the same TXN ID.
                $paymentResult = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM payment WHERE txn_id = '".$txn_id."'");


                 /* if($paymentResult->num_rows > 0){
                    //payment information
                    $paymentRow = $paymentResult->fetch_assoc();
                    $payment_id = $paymentRow['payment_id'];*/

                if($paymentResult->get()->num_rows() > 0){
                    //payment information
                    foreach($paymentResult->get()->result_array() as $row)
                    {
                        $payment_id = $row['payment_id'];
                    }
                    $payment_id = $paymentRow['payment_id'];

                    //order items details
                    $orderItemResult = $this->db->query("SELECT p.name, i.quantity, i.gross_amount FROM order_items as i LEFT JOIN products as p ON p.id = i.item_number WHERE payment_id = '".$payment_id."'");
                    //pass the transaction data to view
                    //$this->load->view('paypal/cartsuccess', $data);

                  }

            }

}
```

and displaying the results in a View file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://{MyDomain}/pauypal/ipn'>
```

Is that typo your actual problem?

What do you see in the IPN history for the PayPal sandbox account receiving payments?

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Comment: hi...no it's not typo.. actually

Comment: **The IPN messages were generated on the PayPal side [Instant Payment Notification (IPN) details]** like num_cart_items,Item_number1, custom, payer_status,payer_email,mc_gross,verify_sign,payer_id,txn_id, etc..

Comment: So, the PayPal IPN history log shows your webserver as acknowledging those IPNs with an HTTP 200 response? What does your webserver log show? You should troubleshoot this issue at that level.

Comment: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history actually holds all the logs of the transactions and the IPN messages have all the details in it, mentioned with HTTP response code 200, with Delivery status as sent.

Comment: That's good. Now you need to debug your webserver and figure out why it isn't processing , or why it isn't validating, or why it isn' saving to the database, each of those IPNs.